# 50000 Ids check in where clause in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have tried below query

```
  $arrIds = array('1'=>'1111'......'50000'=>'50000'); // 50K ids here

  $this->db->select('id'); 
  $this->db->from('mytable');
  $this->db->where_in('id',$arrIds);  
  $query = $this->db->get();
  $result = $query->result_array();
```

Got this error while run

```
**Oops! Something's wrong!**

Severity: Warning

Message: preg_match(): Compilation failed: regular expression is too large at offset 46343

Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 2395
```

Please suggest how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running it in [batches](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
$arrIds = array('1'=>'1111'......'50000'=>'50000'); // 50K ids here

foreach (array_chunk($arrIds, 10000) as $chunkIds) {
  $this->db->select('id'); 
  $this->db->from('mytable');
  $this->db->where_in('id', $chunkIds);  
  $query = $this->db->get();
  $result = array_merge($result, $query->result_array());
}
```

Comment: I have used this code. It's working fine, but I have issues when adds pagination. Suppose I have 50k records, I want 20 records per page. When using 500 chunks, then check 500 at every time. And Last page links like http://url/50000, But record not getting.  Please any solutions.??